# iOS In-App-Purchase Sandbox restoring consumable purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app contains only consumable IAPs. I am attempting to buy the same consumable IAP second time in a row in a sandbox environment, but 3 seconds after the transaction a screen pops up saying that the purchase has been already bought and will be restored for free.

Since the IAP is defined as consumable in iTunes Connect, I don't see how app store wants to restore it. Is this just a sandbox bug and will work when submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IAP is marked as consumable in Itunes Connect. This should solve the problem...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhrll.png

Comment: It is. The problem occurs when I buy the IAP two or more times in a row. If I close the app and reopen it before making another purchase, the problem doesn't persist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish transaction wherever it is `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` or `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```